# mvc4 resource not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Why does the url http://udine.bioen.utah.edu/EarlyAdmits/Admin work, while the supposedly equivalent url, http://udine.bioen.utah.edu/EarlyAdmits/Admin/Index, give an error: The resource cannot be found?

Comment: Do you have an `Index` action in your AdminController ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check route configuration, may be is not configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

**First Check Index page Exist in Admin Controller Or not ??**
If **Yes** Then

May Be you Have Applied **Form Authentication** In Your Project For the Security Purpose Which Is Not Allowing You To Direct Access Of Index Page.

In Form Authentication When You Login On Page Ticket is Generated For the Security..And For The SubSequent Request Every Time It check The Availability Of ticket  Before Rendering any Page..

You Try To Access Index Page So I think It will Not Render..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding an explicit route equivalent to the default route. But I still don't understand why the default route doesn't work.

### Below is my RouteConfig.cs file:

using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace AdmitsWebsite
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Export",
            url: "Admin/Export"
        );
     }
}
```

### }

Without the explicit route trying to access Admin/Export give a "resource not found" error